# PHP page partially loads when it shouldn't

Tags: php, url, server, uri

I have this file structure on my web server:

```
- project
  + css
  + images
  + js
  + utility
    index.php
    about.php
    faq.php
```

Everything works great but whenever I go to the page but forget to put the `.php` on the pages (`domain.com/project/about`) I expect the server to say something like the directory could not be found or the page/resource could not be found. However what happens is that it partially loads the page but it's un-styled because the links to the stylesheets and scripts are now incorrect.

#### Questions

1. What is happening?
2. What can I do to fix it?
3. I don't think I can change any server configurations so how do I fix it on the PHP side?

#### .htaccess

```
# 1 Month for most static assets
<filesMatch ".(css|jpg|jpeg|png|gif|js|ico|woff2)$">
Header set Cache-Control "max-age=2592000, public"
</filesMatch>
```

Comment: have you changed something in .htacess?

Comment: @NicolòCozzani I edited my question to include what's in the `.htaccess` file.

Comment: make your Override and Rewrite off on your server configuration (`httpd.conf` may be) and see the result. Override conf none, and rewrite engine off

Comment: @SSingh like I said on my question I can't make any modifications to the server configurations. We're just piggybacking on a server so we can't do anything about it.

Comment: if you dont mind to load pages without extension,  probably adding a slash before every css and js file is enough and the page should load